# Dynamic "apple-touch-icon" on Android devices?

Tags: android, html, mobile, web, mobile-website

I have an HTML mobile web app that uses a single source of code for multiple branded sites. Each "site" needs to have its own "apple-touch-icon.png" that is used when the site is bookmarked to a home screen. I can get this to work on iOS, but not Android.

We are using Angular.JS for our project, so I've tried specifying dynamic paths in the index.html file directly, for example:

```
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" ng-href="/icons/144/{{bankId | lowercase}}-apple-touch-icon.png">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" ng-href="/icons/144/{{bankId | lowercase}}-apple-touch-icon.png">
```

This works on iOS, but not on Android.

I've also tried appending the  tags via jQuery, for example:

```
$('head').append('<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="/icons/144/'+bankId+'-apple-touch-icon.png">' +
'<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144" href="/icons/144/'+bankId+'apple-touch-icon.png">');
```

This also works on iOS, though there is a noticeable delay for the icon to be populated. Again, this doesn't work in Android.

If I leave the apple-touch-icon.png in the root folder, Android does find it, but this won't work as we need roughly a dozen different possible icons.

Could anyone suggest how else this could be done?